# Can I add widgets in a Recycleview from the kv in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to add Buttons, Labels and Image in a recycleview.But the Screen stayed in black when running the code. I can't see my Buttons. I want this work from my kv.file.. I mean I want to add buttons, labels and images from my kv.file to a Recycleview (Boxlayout or Gridlayout)

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.recycleboxlayout import RecycleBoxLayout

Config.set('graphics', 'width', 360)
Config.set('graphics', 'height', 640)
kv= Builder.load_file('test5.kv')


#Define a RecycleView
class RV (RecycleView):
    pass


class AwesomeApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RV()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    AwesomeApp().run()
```

kv.file

```
<RV>:
    viewclass: 'Button'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None,100
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hinty:None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation:'vertical'
        Button:
            text:"test1"
        Button:
            text:"test2"
        Label:
            text: "text3"
```

Comment: The `size_hint_y` variable in your `RV` class incorrect. You've got it written as `size_hinty`

Comment: I just correct it now. But I can't see my buttons and label yet. I just see a black screen

Comment: You can create your own customized (dynamic) class packing all the necessary widgets as `viewclass`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things are wrong here.

First you're `size_hinty` variable should be written `size_hint_y`.

The second is that your widget properties need to added to `RecycleView.data`.

Try removing the buttons from the `<RV>` class in your .kv file and adding `self.data` to your `RV` class in your .py file. That is:

```
class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.data = [{'text': f'test{x}'} for x in range(1, 4)]
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it straightly from main.kv?? I want to insert not just Buttons, also Labels and Images, and I want to configure the name, id and properties of every Button, label and Images and when I understand that.  later I would Like try to do it in a RecycleGridLayout with 4 columns.

Comment: My bad. I had to use a ScrollView instead RecycleView